# Set form elements of type 'container' to readonly

Tags: forms

I want to set some of the form elements readonly. The problem is, that they are saved as `type=container`. So i'm not able to just set `#attributes` to `readonly=readonly`, like i've done at another element.

Comment: there is no type as `controller` see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#type

Comment: I've edited it, i meant type=container, like i mentioned in the title. sorry.

Comment: `container` Returns HTML to wrap child elements in a container. How can we make a `div` readonly ?

Comment: What @NikhilM said...to make something read-only it has to be writable in the first place, which obviously a container isn't. Could you mean you want to recursively set all children of a particular container to readonly?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers!
In my case I'm showing all fields, that belongs to a user. The standard system fields mail, passwd and so on can be set readonly without any problem. But let's say I added the field "favorite animal". This field is shown as type 'container' when I look at the array with dsm(). :/